# mysql extacted json currency comma excel conversion

Tags: mysql, sqldatatypes

I extracted from a column JSON value a partial JSON string that I will name 'price' here in MySQL. 'price' for simplicity. The original string returned by query is "50,000.00" like common US currency notation where there is a comma every three digits. When I copy and paste it into an xlsx file, it is pasted as a CSV string. In the xlsx file, I use "Text to Columns" in "Data" tab and select "Comma" as "Delimiter". Excel recognizes the comma in currency as a delimiter and splits the digits to both sides of the comma in two separate cells like this.

```
'50 |000.00'
```

I am not sure if there is a solution to prevent this treatment just for this price value in excel level. At MySql query, I want to either cast the value or format it in a way that the query itself returns the price as a numeric type WITHOUT the comma in the first place. I have tried several things from docs and nothing works. **So, how do I convert the return value for price in the following simplified query so it just returns a plain floating number with no comma?** This is a small portion for example but the original dataset is very large so I need to use comma delimiter in xlsx file.
`SELECT price FROM xxTable`

'50  |  000.00'

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many different tries, found out that this does the trick:

```
SELECT REPLACE(price, ',', '') FROM xxTable;
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Help people understand the reasons for your code suggestion.